# How to make a Date Parser in laravel, How to handle multiple possible inputs

Tags: laravel, date, parsing

I want to make a service in laravel SearchDateParser, which gives range as a output in the format:
YYYY/MM/DD-YYYY/MM/DD
or NULL is input is invalid.
valid Query Patterns:

1. D1
2. D1~D2
3. D1-D2
4. D1~ // this means ending date should my  9999/12/31
5. ~D1 // this means starting date should my  1000/01/01

Where D1 and D2 are dates in the format:

```
    a) YYYY
    b) YYYY/M
    c) YYYY/MM
    d) YYYY/MM/D
    e) YYYY/MM/DD
    f) YYYY-M
    g) YYYY-MM
    h) YYYY-MM-D
    i) YYYY-MM-DD
```

this service should also check if date is valid! or atleast give a valid range. How to cover all cases , it is possible to cover all cases. how to do it in laravel

I tried using Carbon library and using regex for splitting, But I was not able to handle such cases particularily:
2023-02-01-2023-02-01
2023-02-2023-02-01 ( What should be the result in this case) , should it be null or should automatically convert as 2023-02-01-2023-02-01?
I am unable to find bug free approach.